# How do I unit test using sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

A.js

```
const func2 = () => 'world';

module.exports = {func2}
```

Util.js

```
const {func2} = require("./A");

const func1 = () => {
    return 'hello ' + func2();  // <= use the module
  }

  module.exports = { func1 }
```

Util.test.js

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const {func1} = require('./util');
const a = require('./A');
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('func1', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(a, 'func2').returns('everyone');
    expect(func1()).to.be.equal('hello everyone');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Getting assertion failure... Sinon stub func2 is not stubbing

AssertionError: expected 'hello world' to equal 'hello everyone'
at Context. (test\util.test.js:10:27)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)

- expected - actual

-"hello world"
+"hello everyone"

Comment: func2 cannot be stubbed like that since func1 already requires the original func2 not the stub you create afterwards, so the asserttion fails reasonably

Comment: Then there is no way  I can test this function?

Comment: as it is coded right now NO, but if you use func2 as a dependency instead of it being required as is , there is a way, called dependency injection

Comment: Thanks Much.. Got it..

Answer (score 1):

If you still want it: change the implementation at Util.js to something like this.

```js
const a = require("./a");

const func1 = () => {
  return 'hello ' + a.func2();
}

module.exports = { func1 };
```

Proof:

```
$ npx mocha util.test.js 


  func1
    ✓ should work


  1 passing (3ms)
```

Note: it is still not dependency injection but little change on how func2 get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can stub out `func2` with [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/). This is the CommonJS version, so we will be using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to construct our seams.

E.g.

`a.js`:

```js
const func2 = () => 'world';

module.exports = { func2 };
```

`util.js`:

```js
const { func2 } = require('./a');

const func1 = () => {
  return 'hello ' + func2();
};

module.exports = { func1 };
```

`util.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('func1', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const func2Stub = sinon.stub().returns('everyone');
    const { func1 } = proxyquire('./util.js', {
      './a': {
        func2: func2Stub,
      },
    });
    expect(func1()).to.be.equal('hello everyone');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  func1
    ✓ should work (1794ms)


  1 passing (2s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   85.71 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 a.js     |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 util.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```